# Docker: Localhost:8080 not responding

Tags: docker, go

I'm running a docker:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t admin
```

The `localhost:8080` is not responding, but I run the `go run admin/main.go` I can reach `localhost:8080` I know that there are many question about this issue, and I looked into everything:

Using the right ports: 8080:8080

I'm able to reach the server while running on my local machine: check that the server is serving the right port.

Here is my Dockerfile - exposing the right port 8080:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 golang:1.19.3-bullseye

# Install grpc
RUN go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.2 && \
    go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
# Install protoc and zip system library
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip && apt-get install -y tree && \
    mkdir /opt/protoc && cd /opt/protoc && wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.0/protoc-3.7.0-linux-x86_64.zip && \
    unzip protoc-3.7.0-linux-x86_64.zip

# Copy the grpc proto file and generate the go module
# RUN /opt/protoc/bin/protoc --proto_path=/app --go_out=/app --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=/app --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative /app/proto/textbear.proto /app/proto/server.proto
RUN /opt/protoc/bin/protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative proto/textbear.proto db/proto/db.proto server/proto/server.proto
RUN go mod download
EXPOSE 8080
RUN go build -o /admin admin/main.go
ENTRYPOINT ["/admin"]
```

I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: I think your entrypoint should be `./admin` not `/admin`

Comment: Post the error message, and the relevant parts of the container log.

Comment: ./admin the app error out because is not found. About error: No errors at all and also no logs.

Comment: I found the problem. This container depends on other container. They need to communicate via grpc and I have not set the network between them on docker compose.

Comment: How is the application setting up its network listener?  Regardless of your Docker configuration, if it's only listening on the 127.0.0.1 container-private localhost address or if it's not listening on that same port 8080 then it won't be reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My admin container depends on the db container network. My admin container was using the `localhost` address and causing the admin container to get stuck waiting to connect to the db container. I fixed by changing the address from `localhost` to `db` and because docker compose will generate the host to all the images, the admin could communicate to db using the `db` hostname.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
version: '3'

services:
  admin:
    image: admin
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  db:
    image: db
    ports:
      - "50052:50052"
  server:
    image: server
    ports:
      - "50051:50051"
```